# RAD Studio (C++ Builder) vs Visual Studio

Tags: c++builder, visual-studio

Приветствую всех зашедших в тему. Вопрос мой навеян многими разговорами, спорами и им подобным. Сейчас учусь в ВУЗе, меня обучают программированию в среде разроботки C++ Builder 2006 (курсач делаю, правда в 2010м билдере). Когда речь заходит о последующем трудоустройстве в качестве программиста, то люди постарше говорят, что работодатель часто узнав, что разработка ведется в билдере, отказывает. Те, кто работает в VS, как-будто на генном уровне презирают и просто ненавидят тех, кто программирует в билдере. В инете тысячи холиваров на тему, почему билдер кака а вс создание бога, НО... сколько я ни просматривал страниц, по существу, почему же билдер хуже вс, сказать не смог НИКТО. Просто хуже и всё. 
Так вот, товарищи программисты, кто-нибудь мне сможет объяснить, почему очень много народу считает, что билдер не надо использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builder приучает использовать готовые визуальные компоненты. Причем эти компоненты заточены строго под Builder/Delphi. Да и библиотека графическая у билдера своя.
В MSVC для графического интерфейса используется библиотека MFC. Для винды она практически 'родная'. Хотя бы в том плане, что включена в изначальный комплект ОС Windows.
Все-таки я считаю, что MFC выглядит профессиональнее. А на 'голом' WinAPI сейчас мало кто пишет: неудобно это, поэтому приходится использовать обертки.
А еще можно проанализировать качество кодогенерации у самих компиляторов Borland и MS. Надо отметить, что компиляторы можно использовать отдельно от сред. Да и в среду можно интегрировать чужой компилятор (так Intel C/C++ Compiler интегрируется в MSVS). И по качеству кодогенерации майкрософтовский CL.EXE на голову выше, чем борланд.
Что еще вспомнить? Драйвера, системный софт тоже удобнее писать на MSVC. А раз удобнее, то значит получается лучший продукт с меньшими усилиями.
Так что каждый сам для себя определяет путь джедая. Никто силком не заставляет пользоваться каким-либо одним вариантом. Но по мне - MSVS лучше и к ней привыкаешь быстро, после чего переползать на борланд становится болезненно. Тем более, когда стоят такие полезные примочки как Visual Assist (для C++) или Resharper (для C#).

Answer (score 1):

В билдере работал мало, но имхо студия хороша тем что в ней приложения могут проходить полный цикл разработки разработка-профилирование-тестирование-публикация. В билдере это всё есть? Если есть то тогда это не засчиытвается. Второй фактор - это то что студия это не только с++ но и c# со всеми вытекающими из него плюшками и бэйсик тоже

Comment: насчет первого пункта не уверен о том, что есть всё. Насчет второго - в принципе неплохо, у меня друг кодит на C# как раз вроде в VS. Но вот не знаю, к сожалению, статистики, сколько программистов, знающих C++, знают C#. Аргументы хорошие, но не видится в таких то, что подмечено в начальном вопросе.